# Redux devtool not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Below is the code to include redux devtool as I read on doc, but it's not working it doesn't matter if I comment out the `intialState` or not.

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools';

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({ realtime: true, port: 3000 });

export default function configureStore(intialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        intialState,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxImmutableStateInvariant()))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That didn't work for me, but this is working.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initalState) {
   const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

   return createStore(
     reducers,
     initalState,
     composeEnhancers(
       applyMiddleware(
         reduxImmutableStateInvariant()
       )
     )
   );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working, but it would be very beneficial if someone can tell, why this worked and why wasn't the previous one working.